# pulling email from omniauth hash to validate user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm using omniauth and devise to log users in with their facebook acounts, everything works however when I try to pull their email out of the hash I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#create
undefined method `id' for "/":String
```

Here's the full log of the error : http://pastie.org/1698569

The error goes away and it lets me log in just fine after I refresh!

EDIT: It turns out that its line 22 in my authentications controller

```
     sign_in_and_redirect_to(:user, root_path)
```

For some reason after running this method I can't sign_in the :user

```
 def apply_facebook(omniauth)                    
   if (extra = omniauth['extra']['user_hash'] rescue false)  
   self.email = (extra['email'] rescue '')
 end
end
```

However, if I don't run that method, then it can sign_in_and_redirect_to just fine

Here's my controllers/model http://pastie.org/1698453

Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `root_path` as the second parameter for `sign_in_and_redirect` . Here are some available ways you can use it:

```
sign_in_and_redirect :user, @user                      # sign_in(scope, resource)
sign_in_and_redirect @user                             # sign_in(resource)
sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication  # sign_in(resource, options)
sign_in_and_redirect @user, :bypass => true            # sign_in(resource, options)
```

Since your second parameter isn't either a resource or options (it's a string), you're getting an error. You need to change it to:

```
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user) # based on your pastie
```

If you want to customize the return path to force it to go to a different URL after sign-in, you can do something like this in your ApplicationController:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  "/go/to/this/path"
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed the issue with facebook, however now I am running into an error when authentications thru twitter. I havent changed any of the other code and I get this error :      ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow in AuthenticationsController#create, it seems it has to do with the 4kb lim it in rails, but how would I get around this?? Thank you very much.

Comment: I switched from session_store to active_record_store and everything works now :)